# How do you make a list in Python based on a keyword within a .txt file?

Tags: python, list, keyword, txt

So the below list is an example of a numeric output, I need to extract data from. It's in the form of a `.txt` file and I'm trying to create a list in Python that searches for a string based on keyword and uses character in that string to make that list.

Specifically, I'm trying to search for "PLT" as the keyword in the `WorkOrder1` row and make a list of the numbers after that. I've searched and searched but the only thing I'm finding is how to convert an entire file to a list and not specific elements within the file. Any help would be appreciated.

```
ART INDEX #1
PartNumber: 123
WorkOrder1: PLT123456
SerialNumber1:  1
SerialNumber2:  2
SerialNumber3:  3
SerialNumber4:  4
SerialNumber5:  5
SerialNumber6:  6
SerialNumber7:  7
SerialNumber8:  8
SerialNumber9:  9
SerialNumber10: 10
SerialNumber11: 11
SerialNumber12: 12
WorkOrder2: PLT123456
SerialNumber13: 13
SerialNumber14: 14
SerialNumber15: 15
SerialNumber16: 16
SerialNumber17: 17
SerialNumber18: 18
```

Code I wrote so far:

```
F_WO=[] 
f_baseplate.append(pd.read_csv(r'\\filepath{}' .format(r'\\'+str(filelist[i][0][0:6])+'\\'+filelist[i][0][0:len(filelist[i][0])-4]+'.txt'), delimiter='\\t',skiprows=36,engine='python',nrows=1,header=None,usecols=[1],index_col=False))
```

What I need is a list generated from the characters after the keyword described above. I want to scrap the code I've got so far as I know there is a simpler way to do this. Thanks for the help, Kris.

Comment: Please provide the approach you tried so far, as well as the expected output you need. People can help you in fixing then quickly

Comment: Do not add code in comments, instead you can edit your original question. Please do next time that

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35773600/how-to-split-file-into-chunks-by-string-delimiter-in-python

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I get you correct, but maybe this works:

```py
keyword = "PLT"
FW_O = []
with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        if keyword in line:
            tmp = line.split(keyword)[-1].strip()
            FW_O.append(tmp)
```

What this does is iterating through all lines of you file. If a line contains your keyword, it splits the line at this keyword and stores everything behind the keyword (except the new line character (`strip()`) in `tmp`. We now append `tmp` to `FW_O`.

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: I appreciate the help! Unfortunately, it doesn't give me what I'm looking for. To clarify, I want to find the keyword "PLT" in the .txt file and store "123456" in the list F_WO. Does that make sense?

Comment: I have adjusted my solution, does it work now for you?

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks a lot!